# Integration of pubsubeat with elasticsearch

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, logstash, google-cloud-pubsub

I am learning how to integrate pubsub with elasticsearch. There are various options like [pubsubbeat](https://logz.io/blog/google-pub-sub/), [Google_pubsub input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-google_pubsub.html), [Google Cloud Pub/Sub Output Plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-google_pubsub.html).

I am currently trying to use pubsubbeat and stucked after running the command " ./pubsubbeat -c pubsubbeat.yml -e -d "*" " as suggested. Log of console is as follows

```
2019-05-23T14:42:19.949+0100    INFO    instance/beat.go:468    Home path: [/home/amishra/pubsubbeat-linux-amd64] Config path: [/home/amishra/pubsubbeat-linux-amd64] Data path: [/home/amishra/pubsubbeat-linux-amd64/data] Logs path: [/home/amishra/pubsubbeat-linux-amd64/logs]
2019-05-23T14:42:19.949+0100    DEBUG   [beat]  instance/beat.go:495    Beat metadata path: /home/amishra/pubsubbeat-linux-amd64/data/meta.json
2019-05-23T14:42:19.949+0100    INFO    instance/beat.go:475    Beat UUID: 4bd6119e-603a-426c-9d5b-6ac588bb000e
2019-05-23T14:42:19.949+0100    INFO    instance/beat.go:213    Setup Beat: pubsubbeat; Version: 6.2.2
2019-05-23T14:42:19.949+0100    DEBUG   [beat]  instance/beat.go:230    Initializing output plugins
2019-05-23T14:42:19.949+0100    DEBUG   [processors]    processors/processor.go:49  Processors: 
2019-05-23T14:42:19.952+0100    INFO    pipeline/module.go:76   Beat name: allspark
2019-05-23T14:42:19.952+0100    INFO    [PubSub: dev/elk-logstash-poc/logstash-poc] beater/pubsubbeat.go:54 config retrieved: &{Project:dev Topic:elk-logstash-poc CredentialsFile:/home/amishra/key/key.json Subscription:{Name:logstash-poc RetainAckedMessages:false RetentionDuration:5h0m0s} Json:{Enabled:false AddErrorKey:false}}
```

On second thought, I tried solution 2 but was getting below error and haven't able to resolve yet

```
io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$NameResolverListenerImpl onError
WARNING: [io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl-1] Failed to resolve name. status=Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Unable to resolve host pubsub.googleapis.com, cause=java.net.UnknownHostException: pubsub.googleapis.com
```

Any lead on how to make thing working will be great help

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved in unexpected way i.e. installing and deploying on fresh machine. Root cause is still unknown.